# What are these two words with obsolete letters?

Tags: буквы, дореформенная-орфография

[image]

I underlined two words in green. They have obsolete letters that I cannot track down. What are the translations?

Context: This is a map legend. The full map is [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_russian_railroads_1916.jpg).

Comment: That could not be Russian Cyrillic. In the title of the map, there is a "western" "I" letter. Also in the snippet provided, in the word "znaki" (please excuse me for not using Cyrillic) the "k" has what looks like an extender. This could be a Kazakh symbol.

Comment: A text in the question is written in [a Russian pre-reform orthography](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F) that was widely used prior to 20th century. It had “i”, “ѣ”, “ѳ” and “ѵ” but lacked of modern “ё” and “й”.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first word is `Уездная` (County, district).
The second word is `Нарым`. It's a geographic title, no translation.

Comment: Okay, so what is that old letter that looks like `п` combined with `ь`?

Comment: I thought it was an л-ь ligature, because I know such a thing exists. But it looks like @Dmitry had identified it as _е_.

Comment: @DrZ214 That obsolote letter is [ять](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C).

Answer (score 19):

First word (Уездная) has an obsolete letter "yat" ("[ять](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C)") in cursive, so it looks different form its typical form (ѣ).

Second word (Нарымъ) has no obsolete letters, although the first letter "Н" is written in uncommon form (maybe someone knows an explanation).

Comment: Nevertheless, writing 'Нарымъ' is obsolete, because now it is 'Нарым'.

Comment: @Dmitry Writing - yes. Letters (the question is about letters) - no.

Comment: Letter "ять" looks different because of used font - it has the same look in the city name "ВѢНА" (Vienna), which isn't in cursive

Comment: Wiki (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C): "... начертание ѣ вроде слитного ГЬ, ставшее в XIX—XX вв. основным в рукописных и курсивных шрифтах, но иногда встречавшееся и в прямом шрифте, особенно в заголовках, плакатах"

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any obsolete letters in that second one. It's [**Нарымъ**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narym).

Comment: It looked more like `Наръ` + w + `жъ` to me, but I confess I am terrible at cursive Russian.

Comment: @DrZ214, *Нарым* is [a really existing minute village](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC), so your theory looks incorrect. And it would be *really* strange looking *ж*.

Comment: BTW there is a cursive `ж` one line upper in an abbreviation `ж.д.` It looks much different from cursive `м`.

Comment: There is plenty of other "ы"s in this document. Same form as in "Нарымъ".